# Show post description outside while loop

Tags: javascript, wordpress, custom-post-type

I've a list of team members (custom post type) that I'm calling using WP_Query class. This part is working, however I'm trying to show the description (the_content()) of a team member outside the while loop when clicked on their name. This container (#team-info) is outside the while loop as you can see in the code. Page would ideally scroll to the description container after clicking on the name.

[image]

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="team-info"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="container mt-15">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <?php
        // The Query
        $the_query = new WP_Query( array (
            'post_type' => 'my_team_sp',
        ) );

        if( $the_query->have_posts() ): $i = 0;
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); $i++; ?>
                 <div class="col-md-4 <?php echo $i ;?>">
                        <a href="#" id="team-name" onclick="myFunction()"><h4><?php the_title() ;?></h4></a>
                    </div>
            <?php endwhile;
        else :
        endif;


        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First, you can get the_content() in while loop with the display: none; and after it, you can show this content in the above section with the jQuery. like if the user will click on a specific team member name their description will show in the above section.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this with `jQuery`. See the below Code.

```
<div class="container mt-15">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php
            // The Query
            $the_query = new WP_Query( array (
                'post_type' => 'my_team_sp',
            ) );

            if( $the_query->have_posts() ): $i = 0;
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); $i++; ?>
                    <div class="col-md-4 <?php echo $i ;?>">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="team-name"><h4><?php the_title() ;?></h4></a>
                        <div style="display: none;"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                    </div>
            <?php endwhile;
        else :
        endif;

        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

Add this code in your `Js` file.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $( '.team-name' ).on('click', function(){
        var teamInfo = $(this).next().html();
        $( '#team-info' ).html( teamInfo );
    });
});
```